# Exist some polyfill for typed on PHP 5.5?

Tags: php

Could do this on php 5.5?

I want return specifically a typed, but i dont know as do this in PHP 5.5

```
function sum($a, $b): float {
     return $a + $b;
}
```

### POSIBLE SOLUTION

Update version of PHP to PHP 7.0+

Comment: You can't specify return types in PHP 5.5; that functionality simply didn't exist; but you can still force a datatype within the function: `function sum($a, $b) {
     return (float) ($a + $b);
}`

Comment: That is invalid syntax for PHP 5.5. Unless you change the core PHP interpreter, there's no userland polyfill. At which point… you might as well upgrade to PHP 7. What exactly is so crucial about this type hint that you need it?

Comment: Yes I did this but I wanted try force the type, if really not exist a real polifyll I tried update to PHP 7.0, Although  I have that change so much in my proyect.

Comment: Most code should run just fine in php7, if it does not, then I would recommend that you fix the issues. Most problems in code is that it uses outdated and buggy/insecure code, which should be fixed anyway! I would also recommend that you skip the 7.0 branch and jump to 7.1 or 7.2 right away instead due to more features (esp in this area).

Comment: Yes really is a small proyect I can change to PHP more and less easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best of logics, but because PHP isnt very type strict:

```
function sum($a, $b){
     return (float) $a + $b;
}
```

Please note that does not throw errors like "expected to be int...". This silently converts all it can to float, which may result in unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: Yes I did this but I wanted try force the type, if really not exist a real polifyll I tried update to PHP 7.0, Although  I have that change so much in my proyect.